# laravel jwt auth, set custom response

Tags: php, laravel, jwt

config/auth.php

```
'guards' => [
    'web' => [
        'driver' => 'session',
        'provider' => 'users',
    ],

    'api' => [
        'driver' => 'jwt',
        'provider' => 'users',
        'hash' => false,
    ],
],
```

Whenever I call api method with expired token, I get this: [image]

As I understand if you set guard driver in config, laravel automatically handles auth errors. But how can I customize this return message  so client would see just message. I don't want him to see this whole stacktrace.

**UPD**: Laravel version:7

Answer (score 1):

This exception can be handled in App/Exceptions/Handler.php

```
/**
 * Report or log an exception.
 *
 * This is a great spot to send exceptions to Sentry, Bugsnag, etc.
 *
 * @param  \Exception  $e
 * @return void
 */
public function report(Exception $e)
{
    if ($e instanceof CustomException) {
        //
    }

    return parent::report($e);
}
```

For your case add this condition to report function:

```
if ($e instanceof Tymon\JWTAuth\Exceptions\TokenExpiredException) {
            return response()->json(['token_expired'], $e->getStatusCode());
        }
```

Comment: can you try changing TokenExpiredException with UnauthorizedHttpException

Answer (score 1):

I just needed to turn off APP_DEBUG.
P.S. *Facepalm* Sorry, everyone)).